# Compiling out-of-tree kernel module against any kernel source tree on the filesystem

Tags: linux, build, makefile, kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to compile a module against any source tree on the file system but I am having trouble with the Makefile. This was the original Makefile I had against the kernel specified:

```
obj-m += new-mod.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

This Makefile would compile correctly, but goal is to have it compile against any source tree. I have tried just:

```
obj-m += new-mod.o
```

I thought that "all:" is assumed but I get error:

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

I have also added:

```
all:
```

to the Makefile with no difference except for error message:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'
```

I have tried a lot of documentation but no luck. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, I used following Makefile  > KVERSION=$(shell uname -r)
PWD := $(shell pwd)
all:
      make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build/  M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
     make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
$(info Building with KERNELRELEASE = ${KERNELRELEASE})
obj-m := assignment1.o

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`goal is to have it compile against any source tree`

ya you can do it providing a `compiled source-code path`

just replace  `make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules`

with this

`make -C <path-to-compiled-src-code> M=$PWD modules`

`make -C /home/vinay/linux-3.9 M=$PWD modules`

try below makefile

Makefile –

```
# if KERNELRELEASE is defined, we've been invoked from the
# kernel build system and can use its language.
ifneq (${KERNELRELEASE},)
obj-m := new-mod.o
# Otherwise we were called directly from the command line.
# Invoke the kernel build system.
  else
    KERNEL_SOURCE := /usr/src/linux
    PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
      ${MAKE} -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} modules

clean:
      ${MAKE} -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} clean
endif
```

In above you can change `KERNEL_SOURCE := /usr/src/linux`-->to.--> your sr-code `KERNEL_SOURCE := <path to compiled-src-code>`

for further info find below liks

[while building kernel modules why do we need /lib/modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805244/while-building-kernel-modules-why-do-we-need-lib-modules/19808044#19808044)

[A simple program on linux device driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586982/a-simple-program-on-linux-device-driver/19587151#19587151)

[How to make a built-in device driver in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542631/how-to-make-a-built-in-device-driver-in-linux/19573806#19573806)

Comment: What if I dont know KERNEL_SOURCE, as I dont know what will be the value for this variable in the target system, so can you provide any other way to do the same.

Comment: Add "CC=<pathToNewCC>" on the make line, like `make CC=/home/myGcc -C <src> M=...`

Comment: `$ make -C ~/stuff/openwrt/build_dir/toolchain-*/linux M=$PWD modules` results in `./include/uapi/linux/types.h:5:10: fatal error: asm/types.h: No such file or directory` so this cannot be all of it ☹

Answer (score 0):

Build against your custom kernel source ( not the one that is installed),
You can use following steps.

1.download kernel from kernel.org (tar)

2.Extract

3.make x86_64_defconfig

4.make prepare

5.make modules_prepare

Now you have to change Makefile to point to kernel source you had downloaded and extracted. Something similar mentioned in example by Vinay Answer.

Just remember you cannot insmod this module as kernel running and module built is for different kernel.